# Changing Grails default index.gsp page?

Tags: grails, gsp

I want to change grails default index page with 1 that i had designed.. In my newly created gsp file which include CSS also the CSS which is not written inside the .gsp file, its out side of it..when i tried to put my css file and index file in app view folder and when i run the app it's not displaying properly showing the error that

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should put your `.css` files into `web-app/css` directory
2. Use [`<g:resource` tag](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/resource.html) to make valid url for such resources (correct url going to be `/prqapp/css/base.css`, not just a `/css/base.css`).

So, your code should looks like:

```
<link type="text/css" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'base.css')}" />
<link type="text/css" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'layout.css')}" />
<link type="text/css" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'skeleton.css')}" />
```

See docs for

- g:resource tag http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/resource.html
- static resources: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#resources
- take a look at *resources-plugin* http://grails.org/plugin/resources